# How to filter all and specific fields using Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, filter, eloquent, filtering

I want to refactor my source code when filtering records in all and specific fields.
Currently, I'm filtering all fields by passing 'search' in my request:
GET request: `/api/users?search=`

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    $search = request("search") ?? "";
    $users = $users->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
        $query->where('code', "like", "%" . $search . "%");
        $query->orWhere("first_name", "like", "%" . $search . "%");
        $query->orWhere("last_name", "like", "%" . $search . "%");
        $query->orWhereHas('department', function ($q) use ($search) {
            $q->where('name', "like", "%" . $search . "%");
        });
    });
    return $users->paginate(10);
}
```

I tried to follow [this article](https://mykeels.medium.com/writing-clean-composable-eloquent-filters-edd242c82cc8), and now my GET request should be: `/api/users?first_name=Juan&last_name=Cruz`
Should I pass `all` request like `/api/users?all=Juan` to filter all fields at once?

What is the best approach when applying this kind of functionality? 
If you know any acticles/resources which can serve as my reference, it would be a great help.

Comment: If you are trying to achieve this for a data table, you can use [Laravel Datatable](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/starts-with-search)

Comment: @Raja Unfortunately, I'm not. I use vue.js on the frontend along with Vuetify

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the article you shared, your url should look like `/users?name=John&last_name=Doe&code=123`

Then, you just call `User::filter($filters)->get()`, and it will automatically apply your query string filters to the query.

If you dont want to implement the filters functionality, you can use eloquent `when` method. It only apply the filter when a given condition is true.

```php
public function index(Request $request) {
    $query = User::query();
    $query = $query->when(request('code'), function($query) {
        $query->where('code', "like", '%'.request('code').'%')
    })
    ->when(request('first_name'), function($query) {
        $query->where('first_name', 'like', '%'.request('first_name').'%');  
    })
    ->when(request('last_name'), function($query) {
        $query->where('last_name', 'like', '%'.request('last_name').'%');  
    })
    ->when(request('department'), function($query) {
        $query->where('last_name', 'like', '%'.request('last_name').'%');  
    })
    ->when(request('department'), function($query) {
        $query->whereHas('department', function($query) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.request('department').'%');
        });  
    });
    
    return $query->paginate(10);
}
```